# translate custom fields in the registration form

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I've installed i18n and added some new fields to the registration form, but I can't translate these new fields.

If I create a view to list the registered users, the string I want to translate shows up in the Translate Interface, but it only works on that page with the users list. The registration form remains untranslated.

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3):

You need the i18n_field module from http://drupal.org/project/i18n. This allows to translate field labels, descriptions and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The core field translation utilities has no user interface, so you'll need the [Entity Translation module](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation).

After installing and enabling it (which also enables translation and locale modules), you may need to run update.php.

Comment: Entity Translation is for translating the content of fields, I think the question was about how to translate the displayed field labels, see my answer.

Comment: @Berdir Yes, I see now. Thanks for pointing that out.